# Chess engine used to point out common tactical blunders

Tags: engines, programming

Does anyone know of chess engines that have been programmed to point out a tactical blunder in plain English?  I.e. “you missed a skewer”, or something to that effect.  Not simply “this move -3”.

Would love to use something like that in bulk on library of my games to see what I should work on.

And/or if it doesn’t exist, I’m an amateur programmer, anybody know where one would begin coding that?

Comment: Welcome to Chess! [Here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/17005/7297) is a related/duplicate question which might help you getting the answer you need.

Comment: Never seen a software like that